# strcpy is not working well with pointer array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, argv, strcpy

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ptr;
    char temp[20];

    if (strlen(argv[1]) < strlen(argv[2]))
    {
        strcpy(temp,argv[1]);
        strcpy(argv[1],argv[2]);
        strcpy(argv[2],temp);
    }

    ptr = strstr(argv[1],argv[2]);
    if (ptr == NULL)
        printf("Non-inclusive");
    else
        printf("%s is part of %s", argv[2], argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter "abc abcd",
I want to get "abc is part of abcd" as a result,
but real result is "abc is part of abcdabc"

Comment: `strcpy(argv[1],argv[2]);` is not really valid. Think of `argv` as `const char argv[]` instead. Don't write to the `char[]`s in `argv`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Writing to the `argv` strings is allowed, but writing past their end is of course not.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't simply do `ptr = strstr(argv[2], argv[1]);`. Why do you have to swap the arguments? In case you tried to make the program check if the shorter string was part of the longer string regardless of their order, then this isn't it.

Comment: @interjay It's allowed, but it's one of those terrible ideas we must resist.

Answer (score 3):

The length of each string in the `argv` array is fixed.  So when you attempt to swap the contents of `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` when their sizes are different you write past the end of the shorter one.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Better to use separate `char *` variables, one pointing the longer string and one pointer to the shorter.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ptr;
    char *s_short, *s_long;

    if (strlen(argv[1]) < strlen(argv[2])) {
        s_short = argv[1];
        s_long = argv[2];
    } else {
        s_short = argv[2];
        s_long = argv[1];
    }

    ptr = strstr(s_long,s_short);
    if (ptr == NULL)
        printf("Non-inclusive");
    else
        printf("%s is part of %s", s_short, s_long);
    return 0;
}
```